# Dropdownlist in yii2 fails while adding style properties

Tags: css, forms, model-view-controller, yii2

my form field code is:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'pvfunctioncode')
         ->Dropdownlist(
             [
                 'Functioncode03'=>'Functioncode03',
                 'Functioncode04'=>'Functioncode04'
             ],
             ['style'=>'margin-left:350px; margin-bottom:-77px; width:265px'])
         ->label(
             'PV Function Code',
             [
                 'style'=>'margin-left:350px; width:300px',
                 'title' => 'Function Code For Process Value ',
                 'data-toggle' => 'tooltip'
             ],
             ['class' => 'dropdown']
         ) 
?>
```

without style attribute it works perfectly,but with style the dropdown not working it remains selected.
i need with style attribute.

Comment: have you tried this? `['options' =>['style'=>'margin-left:350px; margin-bottom:-77px; width:265px'] ]`

Comment: Its not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
echo $form->field($model, 'pvfunctioncode', [
    'labelOptions' => [
        'style' => 'margin-left:350px; width:300px;color:red;',
        'title' => 'Function Code For Process Value ',
        'data-toggle' => 'tooltip',
        'class' => 'labelClass',
    ]
])->Dropdownlist(
        ['Functioncode03' => 'Functioncode03','Functioncode04' => 'Functioncode04'], [
    'style' => 'margin-left:350px; margin-bottom:-77px; width:265px',
    'class' => 'dropdownClass',
])->label('PV Function Code')
```

For more details refer to this [link](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-widgets-activefield#$labelOptions-detail).

UPDATE:

For more options use \yii\bootstrap\ActiveField ([link](https://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap/doc/api/2.0/yii-bootstrap-activefield#$labelOptions-detail)) instead of \yii\widgets\ActiveField